# beginner-deploying jsf web application to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, jsf-2, amazon-web-services, cdi, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am working to create a java web application that uses Java Server Faces (JSF) version 2.1 along with CDI.

Can such a web app be deployed to Elastic Beastalk? I cannot see any option for JBOSS AS 7 (the latest version of JBOSS) so I am a bit confused... Which server do I choose from amongst the options shown in Elastic Beanstalk?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Elastic Beanstalk currently supports only Apache Tomcat for Java Applications. You can deploy an application to Tomcat 6 or 7 using the AWS toolkit for eclipse.

If you are looking for JBOSS you can try OpenShift from RedHat. You can deploy on either JBOSS AS 7 or JBOSS EAP 6 application servers

See alse:

- http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/faqs/
- http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Java.sdlc.html
- http://www.jboss.org/openshift.html